# use Image::Magick with perl on Ubuntu

Tags: perl, imagemagick, dancer2

Image::Magick module is installed.

I do see the perldoc if I type:

`perldoc Image::Magick`

While trying to use it with a Dancer2 application I don't get any results.

A simple test script does compile but except my `hello` I don't get to see any results or warnings? What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Image::Magick;

print "hello!\n";

my $image = Image::Magick->new;
$image->Set(size=>'100x100');
$image->ReadImage('xc:white');
$image->Set('pixel[49,49]'=>'red');
$image->Write("cool.jpeg");
```

Below I provide the relevant parts of the code for the Dancer2 app. On my local (OS X) system everything works fine. On the server the Image::Magick part is not functioning.

As per request the way I use Image::Magick with Dancer2..

```
package myDancer;
use Dancer2;
use Dancer2::Plugin::Database;
use Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible;
use Data::Dumper;
use Image::Size;
use Image::Magick;
use File::Basename;
use File::Spec;
use FindBin;
use File::Copy qw(move);

# --below relevant code--
# UPLOAD-----------
get '/upload' => require_login sub {
    template 'upload', {}, { layout => 'cms' };
};

post '/upload' => require_login sub {
    my $data = request->upload('file');
    return 'Error' if not defined $data;

    my $upload_dir = path( config->{appdir}, "public/images/uploads" );
    debug( "Line 79: ", $upload_dir );

    # full path with file-name
    # $data->basename is the name provided with uploaded file
    my $path = path( $upload_dir, $data->basename );
    if ( -e $path ) {
        return "$path already exists";
    }
    $data->link_to($path);

    redirect '/fm/uploaded';
};

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# What have we uploaded?
#
#vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
get '/fm/uploaded' => require_login sub {

    my $upload_dir = path( config->{appdir}, "public/images/uploads/*.jpeg" );
    debug( "Line: 102 - Full path used for uploaded: ",
        $upload_dir );

    my @images = glob($upload_dir);
    my @glob_uploaded;

    for my $record (@images) {

        my ( $w, $h ) = imgsize($record);

        push(
            @glob_uploaded,
            {
                photo_name => basename($record),
                width      => $w,
                height     => $h,
            }
        );
    }
    my $message = <<'MESSAGE';
  Just a message

MESSAGE
    template 'fm/uploads',
      { forklifts => \@glob_uploaded, message => $message },
      { layout    => "cms" };
};

get '/fm/new-image/:photo_name' => require_login sub {

    # my $curdir = File::Spec->rel2abs('.');
    my $upload_dir = path( config->{appdir}, "public/images/uploads" );
    debug( "Line 137: ", $upload_dir );

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    #
    # What is the latest id?
    # And add 1 to this id.
    #
    #vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    my $sql = <<'SQL';
select seq from sqlite_sequence where name = ?
SQL

    my $sth = database->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute('images');
    my $current          = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
    my $current_plus_one = $current->[0][0] + 1;

    my $new_name = &TimeStamp . "-" . $current_plus_one . ".jpeg";
    debug( "line: 154 - new_name: ", $new_name );

    #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    my $photo_name = route_parameters->get('photo_name');
    debug( "line 159 - photo_name ", $photo_name );

    my $pathFoto =
      path( config->{appdir}, "public/images/uploads/$photo_name" );

    # my $pathFoto = "$upload_dir . $photo_name";
    debug( "line 164: pathFoto", $pathFoto );

    if ( -e $pathFoto ) {

        print "File exists.\n";    # Debug

        template 'fm/new-image', { photo => $new_name, sh_note => $photo_name },
          { layout => 'cms' };
    }

    else {
        print "File doesn't exist.\n";      # Debug
        redirect '/fm/forklift';    # TODO
    }
};

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Adding the new image to the database together with meta-data
#
#vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
post '/fm/new-image' => require_login sub {

    my $new_name = body_parameters->get('photo_name')
      or die "missing content parameter";
    my $caption    = body_parameters->get('caption');
    my $location   = body_parameters->get('location');
    my $short_note = body_parameters->get('sh_note');
    my $note       = body_parameters->get('note');
    database->quick_insert(
        'images',
        {
            photo_name => $new_name,
            caption    => $caption,
            note       => $note,
            sh_note    => $short_note,
            location   => $location,
        }
    );

    my $curdir = path( config->{appdir}, "public/images/" );
    debug( "line: 205 - check path: ", $curdir );

    my $old_image_location_lg =
      path( config->{appdir}, "public/images/uploads/$short_note" );
    debug( "line: 209 - check path: ", $old_image_location_lg );

    my $magick = new Image::Magick;
    $magick->Read($old_image_location_lg);

    $magick->Write( path( config->{appdir}, "public/images/lg/$new_name" ) );


    $magick->Resize( gravity => 'Center' );
    $magick->Scale( geometry => '3%x3%' );

    $magick->Write( path( config->{appdir}, "public/images/tn/$new_name" ) );

    unlink $old_image_location_lg;

    redirect '/fm/recent-images';
};

####################################################### TIMESTAMP #######
# perldoc -q time
# perldoc -f localtime
sub TimeStamp {
    my ( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst ) =
      ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    ( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst ) =
      localtime(time);
    $year += 1900;
    $mon  += 1;
    $sec  = sprintf( "%02d", $sec );
    $min  = sprintf( "%02d", $min );
    $hour = sprintf( "%02d", $hour );
    $mon  = sprintf( "%02d", $mon );
    $mday = sprintf( "%02d", $mday );
    my $timestamp =
      "$year" . "-" . "$mon" . "-" . "$mday" . "-" . "$hour" . "-" . "$min";
    return $timestamp;
}
####################################################### TIMESTAMP #######

true;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us how you are using Magick in conjunction with Dancer2. The example script you show writes to the file system, but you likely want to write into a variable and then render that with Dancer, either by sending it as a file or by making an inline-image and embedding that into your template.

Comment: `my $error = $image->Write($file);` Check for error messages.

Comment: in my simple script this mentions: ```Exception 410: no images defined `Image::Magick' @ error/Magick.xs/XS_Image__Magick_Write/15070```

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code and in the directory where my perl file is, it generated a new jpeg file.[image]

I can suggest checking if your file and directory have the needed permissions for writing new files.

P.S. I am using FreeBSD 13

Comment: Thank you. Without using Image::Magick I'm able to copy and move files over so there should be no problem with permissions. Would be nice to create a thumbnail.

Comment: @Gert: When you say "I'm able..." presumably, you mean your Ubuntu user account is able. But don't forget that your web application probably runs under a different user with far less permissions than you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Dave. I’m trying to find out whether permissions are a problem. Currently the Dancer2 app is successfully moving around files. Also I’m able to write to a database.  

While typing: ```convert -version``` and ```magick -version``` I get to see that I have no **delegate libraries** for Image Magick. Now trying to see how to solve that as without these libraries the code will for sure not work.